# Convert PDFs to JSON based on paragraphs

Tags: c#, itext

I have a collection of pdf files that need to be parsed into json objects.
The key's for the json objects will the the headers(in italics) of the paragraphs in the pdf doc. for example:

```
             *Key one*
                   value for key one is a goes here
             *Key Two*
                   value for key one is a goes here
```

Currently, I'm using itextSharp to convert the pdfs to plain text, but i would like to grab the keys before i do this. Does itextsharp contain a method where it detects italics before parsing it into plain text? if not, is there an alternate method i can use to archive this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are aware that italics may not be clearly determinable?

Comment: I have unfortunately came to that conclusion after much research